# Can a JavaScript webapp support multiple versions of Keycloak servers at the same time?

Tags: javascript, angular, keycloak, keycloak-js

We have an Angular web application which is using KeyCloak and is shipped to multiple customers.

Some of them are using Keycloak version 19, others are Keycloak version 21.

We are using [Keycloak Adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_javascript_adapter) and it is tied to specific keycloak version AFAIK. So currently we ship different versions depending on the Keycloak version.

My question is: is there a way to create a single app which supports both versions?

I could not find anything in the docs describing if we could support multiple Keycloak servers with any of the releases. Or is there any other possible approach?

Comment: You can write your own adapter, that supports multiple versions.